# Smooth absolutely irreducible (?) genus 1 plane pointless curve over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, finite-fields

We got a family of genus 1 plane curves that may violate a bound
in a paper.

Explicitly: Let $F(x,y)$ be the degree 39 polynomial with integer coefficients:

```
x^3*y^36 - 6*x^3*y^33 - 3*x^3*y^30 + 5*x^3*y^27 + 6*x^3*y^24 - 3*x^2*y^25 - 5*x^2*y^24 - 3*x^3*y^21 - x^2*y^22 - 6*x^2*y^21 + 4*x^3*y^18 + 5*x^2*y^19 + 4*x^2*y^18 + x^3*y^15 - 5*x^2*y^16 - 4*x^2*y^15 + x^3*y^12 + x^2*y^13 + 3*x*y^14 + 6*x^2*y^12 - 3*x*y^13 + 4*x*y^12 + 4*x^3*y^9 + 3*x^2*y^10 - 6*x*y^11 + 5*x^2*y^9 + 6*x*y^10 + 5*x*y^9 - 5*x^3*y^6 + 2*x^2*y^7 - 2*x*y^8 - x^2*y^6 + 2*x*y^7 + 6*x*y^6 - 5*x^3*y^3 - 2*x^2*y^4 + 5*x*y^5 + x^2*y^3 - 5*x*y^4 - 2*x*y^3 + 5*x^3 + 3*x^2*y - 2*x*y^2 + 5*x^2 + 2*x*y - 5*y^2 + 6*x - 4*y - 2
```

Let $p=13$. Over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$, $F=0$ has no rational points and
hence no singular points. The genus is $1$.

We believe that it is also absolutely irreducible over the finite
field for the following reasons:

1. Magma's commands k:=FieldOfGeometricIrreducibility(C);IrreducibleComponents(BaseChange(C,k)); suggests it is absolutely irreducible.
2. $F$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{13^k}$ for $1 \le k \le 39$.

The projective closure has only two singular points.

> Q1 Is $F$ absolutely irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$?

In case of positive answer this appears to violate the bound on number of rational points over
finite fields given in the paper ["The number of points on an algebraic curve over a finite field"](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~ftorres/RESEARCH/ARTS_PDF/hkt_sur.pdf), J.W.P. Hirschfeld, G. Korchmáros and F. Torres ,p. 6 Corollary 3.6

Magma online code:

```
p:=13;
Kp:=GF(p);
K<x,y>:=AffineSpace(Kp,2);
f:= x^3*y^36 - 6*x^3*y^33 - 3*x^3*y^30 + 5*x^3*y^27 + 6*x^3*y^24 - 3*x^2*y^25 - 5*x^2*y^24 - 3*x^3*y^21 - x^2*y^22 - 6*x^2*y^21 + 4*x^3*y^18 + 5*x^2*y^19 + 4*x^2*y^18 + x^3*y^15 - 5*x^2*y^16 - 4*x^2*y^15 + x^3*y^12 + x^2*y^13 + 3*x*y^14 + 6*x^2*y^12 - 3*x*y^13 + 4*x*y^12 + 4*x^3*y^9 + 3*x^2*y^10 - 6*x*y^11 + 5*x^2*y^9 + 6*x*y^10 + 5*x*y^9 - 5*x^3*y^6 + 2*x^2*y^7 - 2*x*y^8 - x^2*y^6 + 2*x*y^7 + 6*x*y^6 - 5*x^3*y^3 - 2*x^2*y^4 + 5*x*y^5 + x^2*y^3 - 5*x*y^4 - 2*x*y^3 + 5*x^3 + 3*x^2*y - 2*x*y^2 + 5*x^2 + 2*x*y - 5*y^2 + 6*x - 4*y - 2;
C:=Curve(K,f);
Genus(C);
k:=FieldOfGeometricIrreducibility(C);
//IsIrreducible(C);
IrreducibleComponents(BaseChange(C,k)); 
pc:=ProjectiveClosure(C);
Points(C);
```

Comment: Dear joro, the curve is absolutely irreducible.  Nevertheless, I interpret the last paragraphs of the introduction of the paper that you cite to mean that for smooth curves, the bounds are correct, otherwise, there might be some small discrepancy.  Your example shows that there can indeed be discrepancies.

Comment: IMHO, it would be a counterexample to Hasse-Weil theorem...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik No, it won't be counterexample since Hasse-Weil wants **smooth projective curve** and the projective model is not smooth. On the other hand the projective model of $y^2=f(x)$ is not smooth too...

Comment: well, the 1st comment correctly, I think, points out that Cor 3.6 you cite is only applicable to smooth curves, and your (projective) curve is not.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Thanks. The abstract mentions explicitly singular affine points and there are bounds for the singular points later. Might be wrong.

Comment: @dinamo Thanks. So what are bounds for smooth plane curves? The projective closure of $y^2=f(x)$ is singular too. The "discrepancy" is not small, I have construction for all primes $p$ and for every genus.

Comment: The discrepancy involves understanding the contribution of the singular points.  An upper bound can be constructed using the arithmetic genus of the curve, instead of the geometric genus.  For a plane curve of degree $d$, the arithmetic genus is $\binom{d-1}{2}$.