# Bounds for the number of points on projective hyperelliptic curves over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, finite-fields, rational-points, hyperelliptic-curves

Let $C$ be projective hyperelliptic curve over finite field $K$.

What are bounds for the number of points $\#C(K)$?

The Hasse-Weil bound requires smooth curves, and hyperelliptic curves are
not smooth if the degree is greater than three, having only one singular point.

We have explicit example violating the Hasse-Weil bound with only one singular point.

**abx** claims "A projective hyperelliptic curve is smooth by definition."

For counterexample to abx take $x^6+z^6=y^2 z^4$ and observe that it has singular point over the rationals.

Take $p=29,K=GF(p), C: -4 x^4+z^4-z^2 y^2=0$.

According to sage, this hyperelliptic curve violate the Hasse-Weil
bound, what is wrong with this argument?

sage session:

```
p=29
K.<x,y,z>=GF(p)[]
f= -4*x^4+z^4-y^2*z^2
C=Curve(f)
print(abs(p+1-len(C.rational_points())),2*sqrt(1.0*p))
#11 10.7703296142690
```

Comment: A projective hyperelliptic curve is smooth by definition.

Comment: @abx thanks, I edited with a curve over GF(29).

Comment: This curve is actually elliptic...

Comment: Your curve is singular at $(x:y:z) = (0:1:0)$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thanks, I know this. This type of singularity is experimentally present for all homogenized y^2=f(x), deg(f)>3. I am asking how to estimate the number of points when singularity is present.

Comment: The Hasse-Weil bound is OK for singular curves in projective space, as long as you use the arithmetic genus and not the geometric genus, and as long as the curve is geometrically irreducible. Here you are using the geometric genus.

Comment: @abx I edited with another counterexample to your comment about smoothness.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about meaning of "hyperelliptic curve". Such a curve is indeed always smooth by definition, and the equation $x^6+z^6=y^2 z^4$ does not define a hyperelliptic curve (because it is singular). If you start with an affine curve $x^6+1=y^2$, then this curve can be embedded into a projective hyperelliptic curve, but it will not be the obvious projective closure (indeed, I think it won't even be a plane curve). This smooth model will have either one or two points at infinity, depending on the parity of $\deg f$ in the affine equation $y^2=f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, let $q$ be odd. The question is to bound $\mathbb{F}_q$ points on $y^2 = f(x)$ when there are singularities. Write $f(x) = u(x) v(x)^2$ where $u$ is square free. Let $X$ be the affine curve $y^2 = f(x)$ and let $\tilde{X}$ be the normalization $z^2 = u(x)$, so these are birational by $(x,z) \mapsto (x, v(x) z)$.

Let the degree of $u$ be $2g+r$ where $r=1$ or $2$. Then $\tilde{X}$ is a genus $g$ curve with $r$ punctures, so the Weil bounds for $\tilde{X}$ are
$$-2 g \sqrt{q}-r \leq \#\tilde{X}(\mathbb{F}_q) - q -1 \leq 2 g \sqrt{q}.$$

Let $m$ be the number of distinct roots of $v$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. At each root of $v$, the map $(x,z) \mapsto (x, v(z) x)$ might create a new $\mathbb{F}_q$-point (if $x$ is in $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $z$ is not) or might merge two $\mathbb{F}_q$-points into one. (It also might send one $\mathbb{F}_q$-point to one such point, if $z=0$.) So the bounds for the original affine curve are
$$-2 g \sqrt{q}-r-m \leq \#X(\mathbb{F}_q) - q -1 \leq 2 g \sqrt{q}+m.$$

Finally, if you want to count points on the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, add in one more point at $\infty$, giving
$$-2 g \sqrt{q}-r-m+1 \leq \#\overline{X}(\mathbb{F}_q) - q -1 \leq 2 g \sqrt{q}+m+1.$$

Comment: Many thanks. I am surprised you don't use projective singular points, related question MSE: [Artificially defined curve contradicts the Hasse bound, what is wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899589/artificially-defined-curve-contradicts-the-hasse-bound-what-is-wrong)

Comment: Taking the closure of $y^2 = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is not particularly useful when $\deg f$ is large, since the point at infinity is messy. One could work in other toric varieties, but the notational overhead is high for a simple computation, so I usually just work with affine charts.

Comment: What is a reference for Hasse-Weil for smooth plane curves?  Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332763/pointless-non-singular-absolutely-irreducible-affine-plane-curves-over-finite