Why this genus one curve over $\mathbb{F}_5$ appear to violate Hasse-Weil bound?
Working over $\mathbb{F}_5$, the affine curve $x^4+2=y^2$ has no points.
The projective curve $x^4+2y^4=z^2y^2$ has only one point $(0 : 0 : 1)$.
Both curves appear to violate Hasse-Weil bound of $4.47...$
since the genus is one.
In this question
there is degree $12$ curve with only one point for infinitely many primes,
but it is not absolutely irreducible over the rationals, and our curves
have many points over other primes.

Q1 What hypothesis of the Hasse-Weil bound are these curves missing?


The Hasse-Weil bound is for smooth projective curves of genus 1. Your projective curve is singular at $\infty$.

If you use the arithmetic genus instead, the bound will apply for singular curves as well, but of course the arithmetic genus is larger than one.

@abx Thanks. The hyperelliptic curve x^D+2 z^D=y^2 z^(D-2) has singular point for D>3, does this mean one should be careful about hyperelliptic curves too?

Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396766/bounds-for-the-number-of-points-on-projective-hyperelliptic-curves-over-finite-f

The Hasse-Weil bound applies only to smooth projective curves.
$x^4 + 2 = y^2$ is an affine curve, missing two points at infinity.
$x^4 + 2y^4 = z^2 y^2$ has a singular point at $(x:y:z) = (0:0:1)$ with two rational branches, again corresponding to two rational points once that singularity is resolved.
(I see that while I was editing this answer abx also observed
in a comment that this projective quartic curve is singular.)
The smooth projective curve associated the affine curve  $x^4 + 2 = y^2$ and the singular quartic projective curve $x^4 + 2 = y^2$ has genus 1 and two rational points. Thus $q+1 - N = 5+1 - 2 = 4$ which is indeed within the bound $2g\sqrt{q} = 2 \sqrt{5} > 4.472$.

Also mentioned by @abx.

. . . while I was writing my answer, which also addresses the first curve and the associated smooth curve.  I'll edit my reply to note his comment.

Thanks. The hyperelliptic curve x^D+2 z^D=y^2 z^(D-2) has singular point for D>3, does this mean one should be careful about hyperelliptic curves too?

Yes, one always has to be careful :-)  A hyperelliptic curve C
not in characteristic 2 has affine model y^2 = f(x)
for some squarefree polynomial f.  If deg(f) is odd then
C has one point at infinity.  If deg(f) is even then
there are either 2 or 0 points at infinity depending on whether
the leading coefficient of f is square or not.

I can make the difference between the points and the bound arbitrary large, with only one projective singular point. Is this construction explained again by points at infinity? The details are here
